# Dealing with multiple JSON objects (Android Java)

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am currently dealing with some JSON and apparently running into a bit of trouble. I have a PHP page that fetches two unrelated MySQL requests at the same time and displays both of them, one after the other. I have two JSON encodings. My issue is, I can't get my Java program to recognize the second one. First one is parsed fine.

I ran the JSON through an online validator and it is quite clear those two shouldn't follow as they are now. What is the correct way of dealing with those two ?

Please note that the comma between them (line 11) was added manually because I thought it would help. It didn't.

```
{  
   "player_update":[  
      {  
         "id":"16",
         "name":"Phil_TEST",
         "last_login":"2015-10-12 00:36:05",
         "for_update":"00:00:00",
         "newplayer":"no"
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "player_list":[  
      {  
         "id":"16",
         "name":"Phil_TEST",
         "last_login":"2015-10-12 01:00:42"
      },
      {  
         "id":"15",
         "name":"Phil8",
         "last_login":"2015-10-12 00:50:49"
      }
   ]
}
```

Edit : here's the code I'm using. I can parse the player_update fine, but nothing is done after I ask to find the the player_list, my Logs stop there. Test 00 AND Test 1 both don't display.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stream);

JSONArray arr_player_update = obj.getJSONArray("player_update");
String newplayer = arr_player_update.getJSONObject(0).getString("newplayer");
Log.i("PhLog LobbyActivity", "Newplayer : "+newplayer);

Log.i("PhLog LobbyActivity", "Test 0");
JSONArray arr_player_list = obj.getJSONArray("player_list");
Log.i("PhLog LobbyActivity", "Test 00");
for (int i = 0; i < arr_player_list.length(); i++) {
    String id = arr_player_list.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
    String name = arr_player_list.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    String last_login = arr_player_list.getJSONObject(i).getString("last_login");
}
```

My PHP pages consists of : json_encode($array1);echo",";json_encode($array2);
But the comma is useless. Maybe if my JSON was valid then it would work better.

Logcat :

```
10-12 09:48:00.086 1052-1052/? I/PhLog LobbyActivity: Newplayer : no
10-12 09:48:00.086 1052-1052/? I/PhLog LobbyActivity: Test 0
10-12 09:48:00.086 1052-1052/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for player_list
```

Comment: Flush it all, except for the second JSON,  once youre done with the first. Then send it through the mesh again. It's something that might work. Maybe it's your cache

Comment: What routines you using to parse the JSON? Best solution might be to make two calls to your server, or have your transform this into valid JSON.  If you are using gson, there is a trick you can use to parse multiple json blocks from the same stream

Comment: Can you please post your code for parsing?

Comment: Edited with my JSON parsing code. I think the issue comes from the JSON to parse though, but I'm not sure how to make it valid.

Comment: You should append your both array in a single array and then run json_encode($array);echo;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

The way you are encoding JSON is wrong. That was not an example of valid JSON formatted data. You can check it's validness [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Solution :

You have two different arrays to send as response. Then combine both of them in single array first and then encode it in json format.

Example: (in your php file)

$data_to_send=array();
$data_to_send['player_update']=$player_update; // an array of player update
$data_to_send['player_list']=$player_list;  // an array of player_list

json_encode($data_to_send); // to send the response

Comment: Works flawlessly, I didn't even have to change any other code. Thanks ! So you can't treat with multiple encodes at once, you have to do only ONE code that's got the other ones in it.